# show attributes with user inputs

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a **mysql database** that I'm using with **python-sqlalchemy**
on my 1<sup>st</sup> starting project I have asked to use my database and my attributes in it.

I'm looking for a way to show them by user desires on console like when the user wants to check something specifically he can press 1 and then its gonna come up.

I'm looking for a dynamic function or create one to help through it. Like the code I have here, I want it to show up when user press 1.

I'm not using anything but `sqlalchemy`

```
    Ptable.field_names = ["UserID","Name","TypeID"]
qrt =session.query(users.USER_ID,users.USER_NAME,users.USER_TYPE_ID).all()#worked
for i in qrt:
    Ptable.add_row(i)
print (Ptable.get_string())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not completely clear to me what you want to achieve. I hope I'm on the right track. What I think you want to achieve is:

1. Print a basic list of objects. For example a basic list of cars (I use cars in my example...)
2. Provide the user the possibility to select an object and get more information on this object. In the following example more information on the car.

The example below does not use mysql but this can be easily adjusted. I believe it is less relevant to the main question. Please leave a comment if you want more information on using mysql.

An example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from datetime import datetime


Base = declarative_base()


class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'car'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = Column('created', DateTime)
    brand = Column(String(250))

    def __init__(self, created, brand):
        self.created = created
        self.brand = brand

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{created} - {brand}>'.format(created=self.created, brand=self.brand)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
ex_ses = session()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

for car_number in range(5):
    # Brand maybe not the best name...
    ex_ses.add(Car(datetime.now(),brand = 'Car {0}'.format(car_number)))
    ex_ses.commit()

# Print basic cars list
print('Cars list:')
cars_basic= (ex_ses.query(Car.brand).all())
for car in cars_basic:
    print(car[0])

# Set up loop to accept user input
cont = True
while cont:
    car_input = input('Enter number for more information, x to exit:')
    if car_input.lower() == 'x':
        cont = False
        break
    elif int(car_input) in range(5):
        car_brand = 'Car '+car_input
        print('Details for {}'.format(car_brand))
        print(ex_ses.query(Car).filter(Car.brand == 'Car '+car_input).first())
```

In the example above we create an object Car and add some cars to the database. After creating the cars we print a basic list of the different cars and setup the while loop to get the user input. This while loop will repeat as long the variable cont is True, as long as the user does not enter an x. if the user input is not x we get and print more details about the selected car and continue in the loop.

*This code has to be extended. There is no check of the user input... it is provided as a simple example.*